CKeditor5 can't upload image to backend in asp.net core mvc
I am using CKEditor in an ASP.NET Core MVC project, and I want images to be uploaded via an API to another platform and then return a URL. I am sure this API works correctly with another FroalaEditor.
Through debugging, I found that the issue is that the IFormFile file value is null, but I don't understand why.
enter image description here
Here is the code about CKEditor :
        <div class="mb-3">
            <label class="form-label">Content</label>
            <textarea type="text" class="form-control" id="Content" asp-for="Content"></textarea>
        </div>

<script>
ClassicEditor
    .create(document.querySelector('#Content'), {
        ckfinder: {
            uploadUrl: '/Article/Uploads'
        }
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
</script>

ArticleController.cs
        public async Task<IActionResult> Uploads(IFormFile file)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Uploads files");
            var imagesURL = await imageRepository.UploadAsync(file);

            if (imagesURL == null)
            {
                return Problem("Something are wrong", null, (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            }
            return new JsonResult(new { link = imagesURL });
        }

        public async Task<string> UploadAsync(IFormFile file)
        {
            var client = new Cloudinary(account);
            var uploadParams = new ImageUploadParams()
            {
                File = new FileDescription(file.FileName, file.OpenReadStream()),
                DisplayName = file.FileName
            };

            var uploadResault = await client.UploadAsync(uploadParams);

            if(uploadResault != null && uploadResault.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK) 
            {
                return uploadResault.SecureUri.ToString();
            }
            return null;
        }

By the way, I can successfully run the connector provided by CKEditor.
uploadUrl: https://ckeditor.com/apps/ckfinder/3.5.0/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files&responseType=json

Using the connector provided by CKEditor can successfully run, indicating that the issue lies in the code. I am not sure why the image is not being uploaded to the backend.

In the developer tools, you can check if the correct content data is sent in the request.
